# How do I get the selected text from a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, webkit, wkwebview

My plan is to assign the [selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvJw1.png) to a string variable. But for now I'd like to simply print it in real time. Is there a way to retrieve and assign it in real time?

I've tried to use the answers from the below link and couldn't do much:

[How do I get the selected text from a WKWebView from objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846404/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-a-wkwebview-from-objective-c)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866390/copy-selected-text-with-swift) will help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the selected text from a WKWebView from objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846404/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-a-wkwebview-from-objective-c)

Comment: @DPrice I'll look into that a bit more and see if it works or not

Comment: @LoGoCSE I tried to implement it but I couldn't get it to print the selected text in real time. I don't how to print using "func userContentController" from the solution.