# How to hook/remap an arbitrary keyboard event on OSX?

Tags: macos, hook, keyboard-events, key-bindings

I would like to map:

- <kbd>CAPS-LOCK</kbd> to <kbd>Fn</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> to Left-MOUSE
- <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to <kbd>#</kbd>
- <kbd>RSHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>  to something else
- etc.

I have searched exhaustively for any tool that offers complete freedom for remapping keyboard input, but cannot find one. (Windows has AutoHotkey).

I'm planning to write my own tool that parses a config file.

But how to actually dig in and do this?

Solving this problem will require a thorough understanding of the journey of a keystroke through the operating system, so as to intercept at the appropriate point.

I think I need to eat the event at a low-level, where it is still a virtual key code, then provide my own customised mapping system and inject an appropriate event further up the system.

But where (and how)?

*Edit: I am detailing the results of my research in an answer below (which maybe should be migrated back into the question at some point).*

Comment: As per your end remark, I wonder if you could merge the (excellent) research below back into the question? I won't flag it myself at the moment, but I wonder if it is at risk of being removed as Not An Answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX: Detect system-wide keyDown events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm making this community wiki, please feel welcome to improve it.

Sub-Questions I've asked:

- [Make SHIFT+3 produce `#` not `£` on OSX by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336086/make-shift3-produce-not-%C2%A3-on-osx-by-code)
- [How to tap (hook) F7 through F12 and Power/Eject on a MacBook keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372852/how-to-tap-hook-f7-through-f12-and-power-eject-on-a-macbook-keyboard)
- [How to tap/hook keyboard events in OSX and record which keyboard fires each event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380400/how-to-tap-hook-keyboard-events-in-osx-and-record-which-keyboard-fires-each-even)
  -> **https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDHidLib**
- [Trap each SHIFT key independently on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394032/trap-each-shift-key-independently-on-os-x)
- [In OSX, how to determine which keyboard generated an NSEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394429/in-osx-how-to-determine-which-keyboard-generated-an-nsevent)

I can intercept almost all keydown/keyup events at the bottom of the middle tier. Except for power, and also CAPSLOCK key-UP when it is transitioning from ON to OFF.

Pretty nasty!

Working at the bottom tier level, I can get all key up/down except for the PowerKey.

If it were not for that awkward 75% success rate for CapsLock I would have a good solution. It is vexing that handling a key in such a useful location massively escalates the required complexity.

I have found DDHidLib and am currently looking through it to figure out if it smoothes that problem.

## Research

Googling "keyEventWithType CGEventTapCreate"  seems like a good idea,  as those are essential ingredients for Tapping the event and Re-Emitting it.

Yay! [Modify keyDown output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646108/modify-keydown-output) -- that code compiles, and with minor tweaking (`CGEventMaskBit( kCGEventKeyDown ) | CGEventMaskBit( kCGEventFlagsChanged ),`) I can pick up modifier keys also. I get different keycodes for LSHIFT and RSHIFT. Brilliant!

Problems with the above:

- Tapping kCGEventKeyDown works for some function keys but not others.  It looks as though Apple have only overloaded certain keys, and the overloaded ones seem to get caught at a lower level.
- Power/Eject key doesn't get caught.
- I don't see any way to disambiguate which device the keystroke is coming from.

[How to tap (hook) F7 through F12 and Power/Eject on a MacBook keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372852/how-to-tap-hook-f7-through-f12-and-power-eject-on-a-macbook-keyboard)

http://blog.tklee.org/2008/09/modifiers-across-keyboards.html
-> http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=778484
-> https://github.com/maravillas/dual-keyboards

https://github.com/pkamb/PowerKey may provide some insight
-> https://github.com/pkamb/PowerKey/blob/master/PowerKey/PKPowerKeyEventListener.m
-> [Apple Keyboard Media Key Event Handling -- Rogue Amoeba](http://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2007/09/29/)
... [system wide shortcut for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347862/system-wide-shortcut-for-mac-os-x)
-> http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/361-registering-global-hot-keys-with-cocoa-and-objective-c

Another problem is: LSHIFT-down RSHIFT-down&up LSHIFT-up. The RSHIFT events wouldn't get caught.

Looks like  I need to dip down into IOKit

[Using IOHIDManager to Get Modifier Key Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190852/using-iohidmanager-to-get-modifier-key-events)
-> https://github.com/candera/khordr/blob/master/src/c/keygrab/hid-scratch.c

kEventRawKeyDown in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/
Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/
Frameworks//Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/
Headers/CarbonEvents.h
```

---

## Resources

### 3-tier:

- Cocoa/AppKit is a higher-level wrapper
- Quartz takes the events from IOKit routes them to apps
  *Note: NSEvent is built over Quartz Event*
- IOKit -- talks to the hardware

[image: 3-tier]

#### Top Tier (Cocoa/AppKit)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html -- this document is a must-see, and shows the above basic 3-tier architecture pic. However, it appears to only focus on the top tier (Cocoa/AppKit).

[http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html) <-- this article shows you 3 OSX config files that operate at an even higher level, letting you script your own mappings. This is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000468-611005).

^ [KeyBindingsEditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/) lets you make the above modifications.

#### Middle Tier (Quartz)

[QuartzEventServicesRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html)

[NSEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/) -- specifically [Creating Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/keyEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:characters:charactersIgnoringModifiers:isARepeat:keyCode:)

A couple of working code examples at this level. However, they all perform the same basic trick of receiving one virtual key code and emitting another. So you could use this technique for example to swap 'a' and 'z'.

[Intercept keyboard input in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806256/intercept-keyboard-input-in-osx) -- leads to Quartz Event Taps

[Modify NSEvent to send a different key than the one that was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785630/modify-nsevent-to-send-a-different-key-than-the-one-that-was-pressed) -- Dave De Long provide a working example, also using QET.

https://gist.github.com/wewearglasses/8313195 <-- "Global keyboard hook for OSX" -- another short working demo using QET.

[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) lets you choose which Unicode gets associated with a particular key, or Modifier+key.  Doesn't allow remapping of modifiers, nor does it disambiguate left from right shift keys etc.

[Keyboard input on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809251/keyboard-input-on-osx) -- answer points towards `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` in NSEvent (in AppKit)

#### Base Tier (IOKit)

[IOKitFundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals) <-- Also IOKit ("Interrupt Handling in the I/O Kit... Two types of events trigger an interrupt: ... Asynchronous events, such as keyboard presses")

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Other_APIs/AH_Other_APIs.html

[How can Mac OS X games receive low-level keyboard input events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348886/how-can-mac-os-x-games-receive-low-level-keyboard-input-events) <-- gamers are interested in this!

http://phrack.org/issues/66/16.html#article -- sometimes the hackers present things most clearly, haven't read through this yet. IOKit again, it seems.

---

### More Links...

[How do you implement global keyboard hooks in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894869/how-do-you-implement-global-keyboard-hooks-in-mac-os-x) <-- links to an article.

[OS X: Detect system-wide keyDown events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code) <-- slightly OT as this is just to do with global *monitoring*, i.e. read-only.

http://www.codeitive.com/7QHSeVjPWq/where-can-i-find-kcgkeyboardeventkeycode-list-of-key-codes-for-cyrillic-language.html

Comment: Since the poster wants to remap modifier keys, which do not directly produce keyboard events, I'm not sure that the stuff about intercepting keyboard events is appropriate.  Maybe look at a [custom keyboard layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2056/_index.html).

Comment: Modifier keys do produce keyboard events. To get modifier keys events add the `CGEventType.flagsChanged` to eventsOfInterest eventMask.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out Karabiner (which does all that you want to do.. up till OSX 10.11 .. MacOS 10.12 changed the keyboard driver model, and the authors - mainly Tekezo- are still re writing Karabiner to take account of the new model - this is as of feb 2017)
Karabiner is open source, and you can download the code from Github and twiddle with it.

As part of the re-write they have released Karabiner-elements which works on 10.12 Sierra, but cannot yet do everything that karabiner did.

Karabiner is very powerful, and I miss it greatly on 10.12